# Get account icon and name

Tags: metamask, accounts, web3-providers

I'm using web3.js and metamask-extension-provider in my project to get the signature and public address. Tell me, can I get the name and icon of the account?

Comment: After quick scan in the metamask api I haven’t seen anything about name or icon :)

Comment: For the icon see this question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/120065/how-to-generate-metamask-account-picture.